# how can i make two images collide with each other in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want a code that whenever the player and the fruit collide... to just end the game.

player:

```
playerImg = pygame.image.load('trash.png')    
x = 370    
y = 480    

def player(x, y):    
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))
```

fruit1:

```
fruitImg = pygame.image.load('001-apple.png')    
fruit_x = random.randrange(0, width)    
fruit_y = -600    
fruit_speed = 5    
fruit_width = 100    
fruit_height = 100

def fruit(fruit_x, fruit_y, fruit_width, fruit_height):    
    screen.blit(fruitImg, (fruit_x, fruit_y, fruit_width, fruit_height))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It'll be helpful if you can state your approach. It's called collision detection. Google is your friend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect collision of two images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551594/how-to-detect-collision-of-two-images-in-pygame)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame)

Comment: Please try searching before posting your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect):

```py
fruit_rect = fruitImg.get_rect(topleft = (fruit_x, fruit_y))
player_rect = playerImg.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
if player_rect.colliderect(fruit_rect):
    print("collide")
```

`colliderect` returns `True` if 2 rectangles are intersecting.
[`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a `pygame.Rect` which contains the size of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). This rectangle will always start at (0, 0). The location of the rectangle can be set a keyword argument (e.g. `topleft = (x, y)`)